# After import a csv file how do I filter the data?

Tags: dataframe, filtering

After importing the adult_census_data.csv file, please filter this to include only the following criteria:

State-Gov
Bachelors
Never-Married
Adm-Clerical
Not-in-familiy
White
Male
United States
<=50K

Try use filter the data frame to only include these columns? What's the easier way?

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please read [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). "please help me" is [not a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question); we don't write code to specification. [You are expected to study the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) ahead of time; think of logical steps to solve the problem; figure out exactly where you are stuck, and be able to show exact input and output.

Comment: Please add a tag with the programming language that you're trying to solve the problem with (you can do this after you click on "Edit").